# Change between variables based on selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have two displays/outputs. [A] and [B]. I also have a bunch of functions in a controller that currently just effects [A] through a numpad. I'm trying to create a function that changes what the numpad effects. IE, if [A] is selected, numpad will effect [A]; and if [B] is selected, the numpad will no longer effect [A] but instead effect [B].

Here's what I have:

```
<div ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedInput==='A'}" ng-click="vm.selectInput('A')">{{vm.A}}</div>
<div ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedInput==='B'}" ng-click="vm.selectInput('B')">{{vm.B}}</div>


.controller('selController', function($scope) { 

  var vm = this;
  vm.selectedInput = 'A';
  vm.selectedOutput = vm.A;

  vm.selectInput = function(input) {
    vm.selectedInput = input;
    switch(input) {
        case 'A':
            vm.selectedOutput = vm.A;
            break;
        case 'B':
            vm.selectedOutput = vm.B;
            break;
    }
  };
};
```

And then some functions after that which then will effect vm.selectedOutput, which in theory should change between vm.A and vm.B based on what div is selected.

Sample function which doesn't work:

```
vm.clear= function () {
  vm.selectedOutput = '0';
};
```

Comment: You haven't  asked a question. What's not working here?

Comment: What I have doesn't work and I'm trying to figure out why. If I try to add something to vm.selectedOutput, it doesn't output it to vm.A or vm.B, regardless of selection.

Comment: There is not enough information to pinpoint the problem. Could you create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Did `vm` is a $scope variable or Controller AS ? and Where you declared ?

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Sorry, I forgot to add 'var vm = this;' to my example code.

Comment: I recreated my issue [here](http://play.ionic.io/app/8c94ca807993). Setting vm.clear to the selectedOutput doesnt work. Setting it to just vm.A, does work though.

Comment: @Win [plunker version](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bd6dLgFPUyZwMSzjIjG7?p=preview)

Comment: @nc45 I do not see **selectedOutput** in index.html. Did you forget to use it?

Comment: @win, not quite. I am attempting to make **vm.selectedOutput** BE **vm.A** or **vm.B** depending on the selection. Does that make sense?

Comment: More importantly, is what I'm trying to do even possible? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by creating a data object for my variables.

```
vm.select = {
    A: {
      name: 'A',
      value: '5'
    },
    B: {
      name: 'B',
      value: '6'
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.A = '5';
  vm.B = '6';

  vm.selectedOutput = vm.A;

  vm.selectInput = function(input) {
    console.log(input);
    vm.selectedInput = input;
    switch (input) {
      case 'A':
        vm.selectedOutput = vm.A;
        break;
      case 'B':
        vm.selectedOutput = vm.B;
        break;
    }
    console.log(vm.selectedOutput);

  };

  vm.clear = function() {
    vm.selectedOutput = '0';
  };

})
```

Check out the Plunker code below,
http://plnkr.co/edit/2Iwabg5bJgf87myDdXIg

Comment: This appears to work behind the scenes, but {{vm.A}} or {{vm.B}} doesn't get updated despite it clearly showing that it gets changed from 6 (or 5) to 0. Is there a way to update the DOM with the new value?

Comment: Not Sure, How your answer is related to the question. :P Any how .. Nice :)